# Create an unique ID row that obeys certain conditions on Excel

Tags: excel, uniqueidentifier

I have an excel spreadsheet that looks like this (it was generated by Fragstats software):

```
  Name|  Type  |Covered Area|Perimeter|Area(m²)|...
     0| habitat|...
     0|not hab |...
     1|not hab |...
     1| habitat|...
     2|not hab |...
```

Please notice that my is organized in three different patterns:

**1- First row = habitat; second row = no hab**
**2- First row = no hab; second row = habitat**
**3- Only one row with either habitat or no hab**

What I want to do is create an ID column on the very left side only on the rows that have **type = habitat**, skipping all "not hab" in the middle so I can import that information later on another table with the VLOOKUP function. I tried filtering the table using **type** as criteria, but if I do so, I cannot copy and paste the data effectively (it pastes on hidden cells as well, assigning the values to the wrong rows). Basically, what I need is an ID column that has the same number as the **Name** column, but it returns a blank space on every type = no hab row. I thought a formula would do it, but I'm all out of ideas.

Also, I don't really know how to use VBA or any other programming language, so unless you post a complete tutorial teaching how to apply the solution, I'm afraid the answer won't be useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you simply use this formula?

```
=IF(C21="not hab",B21,"")
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. I don't know why, but this function only returns blank spaces. It doesn't recognize the string as TRUE. Do you know how can I overcome this?

Comment: Check if the word has spaces or has multiple lines that are not visible. Else post a screenshot of the formula bar with the "not hab" selected

Comment: Got it. It turns out that the word not only had a space after it (which I had already taken into consideration) but also before. Now the function works just fine. I Appreciate the help.